# Adding multiple user inputs to a dictionary and writing them to csv, python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, tkinter

First post on here! I am currently learning python mainly with tkinter to make a GUI that will accept user inputs and save them to a csv.

I have it taking and saving user inputs but i think it would be more benifical to save all the inputs to a dictionary and then call the whole dictionary to be saved to csv.
So far i have this, i dont like the way i'm conintually writing to the csv one after each other. I'd rather call the whole dictionary. I had thought something like

```
inputs = {'name':'self.input1.get()', 'age':, 'self.input2.get()'}
```

doesn't seem to be working though? Code is below thanks!

```
from tkinter import * 
import csv

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.output()

    def output(self):
        Label(text='Name:').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5,pady=5)
        self.input1 = Entry(root, width=10)
        self.input1.grid(row=0, column=1,padx=5,pady=5)

        Label(text='Age:').grid(row=1, column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.input2 = Entry(root, width=10)
        self.input2.grid(row=1, column=1,padx=5,pady=5)      


        self.b = Button(root, text='Submit', command=self.writeToFile)
        self.b.grid(row=4, column=4,padx=5,pady=5)



    def writeToFile(self):
        with open('WorkOrderLog.csv', 'w') as f:
            w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            w.writerow([self.input1.get()])
            w.writerow([self.input2.get()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    root.title('Auto Logger')
    root.geometry('1000x100')
    app=App(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You might investigate the `json` module - dictionaries lend themselves well to being turned into JSON, and you get to preserve all the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need separate the submission and write processes into their own functions. I would suggest creating an array that you append dictionaries to. For example

```
self.data = [
    {'name': 'John', 'age':23},
    {'name': 'Sally', 'age':26},
]
```

Then when it comes time to write your data to a file, you can iterate over your list to write each line of the csv.

You can create an initially empty array like `self.data = []` and then add to it with something like `self.data.append({'name': self.input1.get(), 'age': self.input2.get()})`. When it comes time to write it to a csv, you can iterate over it.

Comment: I understand that makes sense, when calling into these dictionaries will for example self.input1.get() work? So far all i've seen is people having the dictionaries preset like your example above

Comment: I added an example of how you might append to the array as you enter new data.

Comment: Thank you! i added it to my code and its throwing the error  w.writerow([self.data.get()])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Yes, lists don't have a `get()` method. What you want to do is iterate over the dict using a for loop `for data_entry in self.data`, and then to write each line you would do something like `w.writerow([data_entry['name'], data_entry['age']])`. Remember, every `data_entry` is itself a dictionary, so it is essentially an associative array. The indexes are whatever key you use when you add the dictionary to `self.data`.